# How to $watch multiples properties simultaneous and interpolate into one expression?

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, expression, string-interpolation

Suppose two input fields - name and text. How to simultaneous watch this two fields and interpolate their value into one expression?

Thanks!

**Update 9/7/2014:** 
   I did this **[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Siacof9LLUWM2wzdIAlW?p=preview)** with a working version of the code :)

Thanks Mohammad Sepahvand!

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
      <title>Interpolate String Template Example</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('myApp', ['emailParser']).controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'EmailParser', function ($scope, EmailParser) {
          // init
          $scope.to = '';
          $scope.emailBody = '';

          $scope.$watchCollection('[to, emailBody]', function (newValues, oldValues) {
            // do stuff here
            // newValues and oldValues contain the new and respectively old value
            // of the observed collection array
            if (newValues[0] && newValues[1]) { // there's name and some text?
              $scope.previewText = EmailParser.parse(newValues[1], {to: $scope.to});
          }
        });
        }]);

        angular.module('emailParser', []).config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
          $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('__');
          $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('__');
        }]).factory('EmailParser', ['$interpolate', function ($interpolate) { // create service
          return {
            parse: function (text, propertiesToBeInterpolated) { // handle parsing
              var template = $interpolate(text);
              return template(propertiesToBeInterpolated);
            }
          };
        }]);
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h3>Instructions in readme.md file - please read before!</h3>
      <div id="emailEditor" ng-controller="MyController">
        <label>*Name:</label>
        <input ng-model="to" type="text" placeholder="Ex.: John"/>
        <br><br>
        <label>*Text:</label><br>
        <textarea ng-model="emailBody" cols="25" rows="10" placeholder="Write something"></textarea>
        <p style="color:red;">*required</p>
        <div>
          <pre>__previewText__</pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$watchGroup` method that was added in angular 1.3:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['prop1', 'prop2'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
   var prop1 =newValues[0];
   var prop2 =newValues[1];
});
```

Or you could use `$watchCollection` which has been available since angular 1.1.4:

```
scope.$watchCollection('[prop1, prop2]', function(newValues, oldValues){

});
```